# Which way to write ㅊ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, hangul

Which is the better way to write ㅊ?
I've seen it written in 3 different ways like in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

None of the above: they are all shapes used for printed characters, just like lowercase "a" or "g" of, say, Times Roman (see the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman)).

For handwriting, see the picture below.  (Stolen from [here](https://bulkwang.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80-%EC%9E%90%EC%9D%8C-%ED%9A%8D%EC%88%9C-%EC%93%B0%EA%B8%B0-%EC%97%B0%EC%8A%B5-3/).)

[image: 한글 획순]

Comment: Is this a standard? I personally have different stroke orders for ㅌ and ㅍ.

Comment: Not sure if there's an official standard, but this is exactly how I learned it at school.

Answer (score 0):

The first and second can be frequently seen in korean web page. And the
third is used by calligrapher. With a large brush, they write with
third way in a big paper frequently. In further, some people write with the third way in a note. Usually, almost people use the way in jick's answer.